# I haven’t had this much fun since like ever. from a moive: Astro Boy

Tags: grammar

Is this grammatically possible?

> I haven’t had this much fun since like ever.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the grammar?  If you do not, your question may be closed as 'too general'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in standard written English

In speech, what is happening here is two different structures have been mixed

> I haven't had this much fun since (last year/ I was 10).

> I haven't had this much fun ever.

The speaker begins with the first sentence, and reaches "since". Then realise that they can't think of the time when they had more fun, and (using "like" to fill the thinking time) switches to the second structure.  If this was written English you would just cross out the word "since" (and "like")  But you can't cross things out in spoken English.

Introducing this kind of mistake, or change of structure makes the spoken English sound much more natural for the children who are speaking.

It's a mistake, but this kind of mistake is natural in spoken English.